# D3.js: is it possible to make a sync xhr request?

Tags: d3.js

Is it possible to make synchronous ajax requests using d3.xhr (and/ or any of it's convenience methods) ?
I am talking about something like jQuery's async: false option.  10x

Comment: and you need this because ...

Comment: Is this pertinent to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** but there is still hope. The "a" in "ajax" may stand for "asynchronous", but third argument of [XMLHttpReques.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/XMLHttpRequest#open%28%29) is sometimes useful. You can't do synchronous requests with d3 because it has that option [hardcoded to be true](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/xhr/xhr.js#L94). So if you really need to, you can override that behavior (generally it's not cool to mess with library code though) or simply use a callback to kick off execution of whatever you need after data is loaded and processed.